# Iterate 3 vectors split contents and assign

Tags: java

I have 3 vectors with similar format like the following..

Vector1:

```
start:231 stop:234 name:xyz 
start:331 stop:334 name:abc
start:431 stop:434 name:fds
```

Vector2 and vector3 also have same format.
I have to iterate the 3 vectors and split the contents and assign to strings or integers.

I have done like the following:

```
public static  Tokens getTokens( Vector<NameBuffer> vc1 ) {
    Tokens tokens=new Tokens();
    Iterator it1=vc1.iterator();
    while(it1.hasNext())
    {
    String onerecord=  it1.next().toString();
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(onerecord);
    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {

        String tmp = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
        if ( tmp.startsWith("start=")) {
            tmp = tmp.substring("start=".length());
            try {
                int begin = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
                tokens.setbegin(begin);
            }
            catch ( NumberFormatException nfe ) {
                nfe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            System.err.println("Wrong format");
        } 
        String tmp1 = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
        if ( tmp1.startsWith("stop=")) {
            tmp1 = tmp1.substring("stop=".length());
            try {
                int end = Integer.parseInt(tmp1);
                tokens.setend(end);
                //System.out.println(end);
            }
            catch ( NumberFormatException nfe ) {
                nfe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            System.err.println("Wrong format");
        } 
                    String tmp2 = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
        if ( tmp2.startsWith("name=")) {
            tmp2 = tmp2.substring("name=".length());

                String name = tmp2;
                tokens.setname(name);

            }

        }
        else {
            System.err.println("Wrong format");
        } 
    }//while(stringtokenizer.hasmoreElements

    System.out.println(tokens);// At this point i was able to print all records

}//while(it1.hasNext()

    return tokens; //Is the problem with this return?

}//getTokens
```

---

Note:Tokens is a simple Java class with setters and getters like setstart() and gerstart()

In the main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      Tokens fnTokens=getTokens(vector1);
      for(i=0;i<firstname.size();i++)
      {
      System.out.println(fnTokens);// it is printing only last record in my vector
      }

}
```

If I print in the `getTokens` method itself I was able to get all records, but here only the last record.

My final intention is iterate all 3 vectors and compare the elements like vector1.getstart(),vector1.getend() and vector1.getname()
vector2.getstart(),vector2.getend() and vector2.getname()
vector3.getstart(),vector3.getend() and vector3.getname()

Can some one help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You keep overwriting the single `Tokens` instance you have... In your original code:

```
Tokens tokens=new Tokens();//create Tokens instance
while(it1.hasNext())
{
  // init
  while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
   // set tokens fields
  }
  System.out.println(tokens);// You print the current Tokens instance

}//while(it1.hasNext()
return tokens; //only return one, at the last state.
```

And in the loop, you always print the **current state** of the `Tokens` instance, but return only the **last**.

To solve, change the method around a bit to return all instances, for example in a List:

```
public static  List<Tokens> getTokens( Vector<NameBuffer> vc1 ) {

  List<Tokens> tokenList=new ArrayList<Tokens>();//create Tokens list to return
  while(it1.hasNext())
  {
    // init
    Tokens tokens=new Tokens();//create Tokens instance inside loop
    tokenList.add(tokens); //add to list to return 

    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
     // set tokens fields -- unchanged
    }
    System.out.println(tokens);// You print the current Tokens instance

  }//while(it1.hasNext()
  return tokenList; //only return the last one....
}
```

And then in the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //...

  List<Tokens> fnTokens=getTokens(vector1);
  for(Tokens t: fnTokens)
  {
    System.out.println(t);      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static  Tokens getTokens( Vector<NameBuffer> vc1 ) {
   Iterator it1=vc1.iterator();
   while(it1.hasNext()) {
       String onerecord=  it1.next().toString();
      //String onerecord="start:231 stop:234 name:xyz";
       String ss[]=onerecord.split(":|\\s");
       System.out.println(ss[0]+" = "+ss[1]);
       System.out.println(ss[2]+" = "+ss[3]);
       System.out.println(ss[4]+" = "+ss[5]); 
   }
}
```